# Stack/GHC Permission Error: "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: haskell, gcc, ghc, haskell-stack

I am trying to use stack to build a simple project (created with`stack new simple`) but when I run `stack build` I get the following error:

```
configure: error: in `/Users/xxx/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.3.temp/ghc-8.8.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

It seems like there is a permissions issue with gcc as running `configure` manually with sudo completes successfully:

```
cd /Users/xxx/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.3.temp/ghc-8.8.3
sudo ./configure
```

I have also checked that I can compile and c files with gcc and run the outputs successfully.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Output of config.log for failed build:

```
configure:3853: $? = 1
configure:3873: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3895: clang  -l/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -l/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3899: $? = 1
configure:3937: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ghc-8.8.3"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "8.8.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System 8.8.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "glasgow-haskell-bugs@haskell.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3942: error: in `/Users/xxx/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.3.temp/ghc-8.8.3':
configure:3944: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Have you tried fixing the first error? The one reading  `library not found for -l/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include`?

Comment: Sigh... so obvious lol. `export CPPFLAGS=-l/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include` had this in my .zshrc. @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks! Appreciate the help!

Comment: A pleasure - it's always the one our eyes miss... that's why more eyes help.